# Java - Encryption/Decryption error

Tags: java

In our java application, we create a encrypted zip using JDK JCA API. The algorithm used is password based encryption PBEWithMD5AndDES. The issue we face is during unzip, it fails to unzip with below exception intermittently.

```
Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED;`  
`java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58);`  
`java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toStringUTF8(ZipCoder.java:117);`  
`java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:297);`  
`java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:121);`
```

Most of the time it fails at the ZipFile,ZipEntry utility classes from the API during decryption.

Could please provide some input on the above issue.

The charset for encoding we use is Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
Does this contributing for the issue as we see the error related from the above stack trace as java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toStringUTF8(ZipCoder.java:117)

The charset is not set before. Here is how we read it,

```
try { zipFileInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile)); 
    ZipEntry zipEntry = null; 
    while ((zipEntry = zipFileInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
       String zipEntryFileName = zipEntry.getName(); 
       if (StringUtils.isExactMatch(fileHasWeekNumberRegEx, zipEntryFileName)) {      
        //do something break; 
       } 
    } 
} 
catch (IOException e) { } 
finally { 
    zipFileInputStream.close(); 
}
```

But this works for other encrypted zips even if it is not set. Not all zips work properly.This issue happens intermittently.

Any help will be appreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem surely revolves around details of your code, none of which you have provided.  We expect you to prepare and present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem to get a useful answer to a question of this kind.  As a bonus, the process of preparing an MCVE may itself lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The charset is not set before. Here is how we read it,

```
try {
    zipFileInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

    while ((zipEntry = zipFileInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        String zipEntryFileName = zipEntry.getName();
        if (StringUtils.isExactMatch(fileHasWeekNumberRegEx, zipEntryFileName)) {
            //do something
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
} finally {
    zipFileInputStream.close();
}
```

But this works for other encrypted zips even if it is not set. Not all zips work properly.This issue happens intermittently.

Comment: This did not fix the problem. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies about encoding `Charset.forName("US-ASCII");`. The code doesn't set any encoding but instead uses the default one which is windows-1252 in my case. Tried setting the charset for the one which is windows-1252 but still no luck. We have checked for Input and output stream objects being open and made sure all stream objects are closed properly. Any suggestion on other cause which is potentially contributing for the issue?